# Dismiss Numeric Keyboard WP8 in Code Behind (VB)

Tags: textbox, windows-phone-8, keyboard

So I have a Numeric Keyboard for entering a few numbers and according to other apps and questions the best way to put a Done/Cancel button is with the Application Bar which I have already setup without any issues. My only problem now is that when I do click on the done or cancel button I want to dismiss the keyboard as well but I can't seem to figure this part out. I've seen a few other posts say to use this.Focus(); but that's for C# and I'm using VB instead and so far haven't been able to find a similar function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page still has a method called 'Focus()' in VB.  The problem is that:

(C#) **this**  is (VB) **Me**

So, it's:

```
Me.Focus()
```

Or, simply:

```
Focus()
```